# How to get true LIFO order, out of the stack?

Tags: java, stack, lifo

How to add int values and then iterate through stack getting LIFO order? Adding 7 and 1 returns 7 and 1.

```
   public void calculate_10to99() {

    Stack romanNumeralsStack =  new Stack();
        romanNumeralsStack.add(7);
        romanNumeralsStack.add(1);

        Iterator value = romanNumeralsStack.iterator();

    while (value.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(value.next());
    }
```

Comment: Use a `Deque`. Specifically, use an `ArrayDeque`. **Read** the [`Stack` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html). It says (in part) *A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.*

Comment: Why would you use a stack if you need FIFO order?

Comment: In the title of the question, you mentioned LIFO  but in the description you want FIFO. Please clear the question.

Comment: Don't use the iterator, just use romanNumeralsStack.push() instead of add() and pop() to remove and you should get LIFO

Comment: @oxy_js I think mat1 means that he is expecting LIFO order but getting FIFO order

Comment: FIFO was a mistake, its corrected now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Collections (LIFO Structure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302460/java-collections-lifo-structure)

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
public void calculate_10to99() {

    Stack<Integer> romanNumeralsStack =  new Stack<>();
        romanNumeralsStack.push(7);
        romanNumeralsStack.push(1);

    while (!romanNumeralsStack.empty()){
        System.out.println(romanNumeralsStack.pop());
    }
 }
```

The iterator() method comes from its superclass Vector and just returns all of the elements in order, so iterator.next() does not give you LIFO

Comment: What type of instance does `romanNumeralsStack.pop()` returns? `System.out.println(romanNumeralsStack.pop())` pops and print the number from the stack, but   `int temp = romanNumeralsStack.pop()`  doesnt work, neither `Integer` or `String`. Only `Object` works. What type of object is popped from stack?

Comment: For return type you need to define stack as  Stack<Integer> romanNumeralsStack = new Stack(); then only you can use int tmp = romanNumeralsStack.pop()

Answer (score 1):

You are using iterator as

```
Iterator value = romanNumeralsStack.iterator();
```

Which return element in random order from what was present in the stack.

You should use another method such as. This will check if the stack is not empty then it keeps on popping element from the top which makes it LIFO.

```
public static void calculate_10to99() {

        Stack romanNumeralsStack = new Stack();
        romanNumeralsStack.add(7);
        romanNumeralsStack.add(1);

        while (!romanNumeralsStack.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(romanNumeralsStack.pop());

        }
    }
```